# How to truncate a numpy/scipy exponential distribution in an efficient way?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, distribution

I'm currently building a neuroscience experiment. Basically, a stimulus is presented for 3 seconds every x seconds (`x = inter-trial interval`). I would like x to be rather short (`mean = 2.5`) and unpredictable.

My idea is to draw random samples from an exponential distribution truncated at 1 (lower bound) and 10 (upper bound). I would like the resulting bounded exponential distr. to have an expected mean of 2.5. How could I do that in an efficient way?

Comment: If you want the samples bounded, why are you choosing an exponential distribution?

Comment: Note that if you start with a exponential distribution with mean 2.5, and then truncate to the interval [1, 10], the mean of the truncated distribution is not 2.5. In fact, it is about 3.25.

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways to do this:

The first is to generate an exponentially distributed random variable and then limit the values into (1,10).

```
In [14]:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as ss
Lambda = 2.5 #expected mean of exponential distribution is lambda in Scipy's parameterization
Size = 1000
trc_ex_rv = ss.expon.rvs(scale=Lambda, size=Size)
trc_ex_rv = trc_ex_rv[(trc_ex_rv>1)&(trc_ex_rv<10)]
In [15]:

plt.hist(trc_ex_rv)
plt.xlim(0, 12)
Out[15]:
(0, 12)
```

[image]

```
In [16]:

trc_ex_rv
Out[16]:
array([...]) #a lot of numbers
```

Of course, the problem is you are not going to get the exact number of random numbers (defined by `Size` here).

The other way to do it is to use [Inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), and you will get the exact number of replicates as specified:

```
In [17]:
import numpy as np
def trunc_exp_rv(low, high, scale, size):
    rnd_cdf = np.random.uniform(ss.expon.cdf(x=low, scale=scale),
                                ss.expon.cdf(x=high, scale=scale),
                                size=size)
    return ss.expon.ppf(q=rnd_cdf, scale=scale)
In [18]:

plt.hist(trunc_exp_rv(1, 10, Lambda, Size))
plt.xlim(0, 12)
Out[18]:
(0, 12)
```

[image]

If you want the resulting bounded distribution to have an expected mean of a given value, say `2.5`, you need to solve for the scale parameter that resulting the expected mean.

```
import scipy.optimize as so
def solve_for_l(low, high, ept_mean):
    A = np.array([low, high])
    return 1/so.fmin(lambda L: ((np.diff(np.exp(-A*L)*(A*L+1)/L)/np.diff(np.exp(-A*L)))-ept_mean)**2,
                     x0=0.5,
                     full_output=False, disp=False)
def F(low, high, ept_mean, size):
    return trunc_exp_rv(low, high,
                        solve_for_l(low, high, ept_mean),
                        size)
rv_data = F(1, 10, 2.5, 1e5)
plt.hist(rv_data, bins=50)
plt.xlim(0, 12)
print rv_data.mean()
```

Result:

```
2.50386617882
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this distribution will not have a mean of 2.5, which is what @user1363251 asks for in the first paragraph of the question.

Comment: Yes, I notice that. Not entirely sure if the OP want to truncate an exponential distribution with expected mean of 2.5 or want the resulting bounded exponential distr. to have an expected mean of 2.5. If he can clarified that it can be easily done. The expect mean probably can be easily express in a closed from.

Comment: I don't understand how you mean that the truncating is made, if you use hist (which "groups" the input) and then xlim in plot. The problem is that given a large sample, e.g. 1000, of rvs. How to filter them to get only the ones that fit into a given range. The rvs are unordered.

Comment: `>>> a = expon.rvs(size=10, scale=4)`
`array([6.05231017, 5.71233108, 1.74126937, 0.57614087, 7.5496941 ,
       2.84520597, 3.06463358, 2.84783107, 1.84672096, 4.45238162])`
`>>> np.mean(a)`
`3.6688518790529456`
`>>> np.sort(a)[0:5]`
`array([0.57614087, 1.74126937, 1.84672096, 2.84520597, 2.84783107])`
`>>> np.mean(np.sort(a)[0:5])`
`1.9714336475094363 # different mean!`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @CT Zhu's great answer, it appears that `scipy` now has a [truncated exponential distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncexpon.html#scipy.stats.truncexpon) built-in.

```
from scipy.stats import truncexpon
r = truncexpon.rvs(b, size=1000)
```